# Get a list of changed files between two versions in maven

Tags: java, maven, svn, ant

I am researching a way to port an **extremely convoluted** legacy ant script to a maven project, and I need the option to get a list of changed files between two versions.

A little (sad) history: this project uses ant to build the app in an exploded format (i.e. compiled classes) to an output directory. Those compiled files are then stored in SVN (I know...). The application is running as a Windows Service (using [Windows Service Wrapper](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw)), and the "deployment" process is simply copying over the changed class files (done by running `svn update` on the production server) (I know...........).

My first and foremost goal is to stop this project storing binaries in SVN and to start using maven! However, due to the way everything else already works, there are 2 requirements:

1. Have Maven keep building the "exploded" classes
2. Ability to get a "diff" between two version releases

I guess #1 is already done for me by Maven, I can find the classes in the `targets` directory. My question is, is it possible to somehow have Maven give me just the classes that were changed? Maybe not as files, but as a sort of changelog (which I could parse myself)?

And of course, I know that **we're doing it wrong**, so any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at `scm` plugin `diff` goal http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/diff-mojo.html and `changelog` plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changelog-plugin/. Also you do know that you can fire ant tasks from maven, right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I feel you.

And to the question:
If files from previous release are stored in SVN you could try to checkout them to some temp directory, copy over your newly compiled files and just generate svn diff on this folder (and subfolders).

Comment: The [maven-scm-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) might help if you try this option.